# Problem of Jmeter/Webdriver with testing a webapp searching data form which has Knockout installed

Tags: testing, knockout.js, jmeter, webdriver

I am facing problem  of testing jmeter/Webdriver for a webapp which has Knockout framework installed. I fill all the form fields OK but when run click search button it displays the error that required fields need not to be empty. I checked all web element value are not empty. As my understand Knockout is not activated to bind Web elements with DataModel from Knockout. I used wait  WDS.browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait for webpage fully loaded/ajax calling or event being fired but without any success. I Do you have any experiencing and solution for testing this kinds of webapp?

thanks

Comment: Webdriver is something related to Selenium and not part of JMeter's universe by default. I would suggest debugging the issue with pure selenium based environment and then migrating it to JMeter in case have such a use case. This is not specific JMeter issue as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case you need to trigger a certain [JavaScript event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) in order to "tell" the web application that you finish the input, i.e. [onkeyup](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) or [onblur](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp) which is not being automatically called by Selenium's [sendKeys() function](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebElement.html#sendKeys-java.lang.CharSequence...-)

You can use i.e. [WDS.browser.executeScript()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) function to send the event(s) which indicate that you filled in the form(s). Check out [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered) article to learn how to call scripts, use [Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/), etc.